# Рефлексия и массив с++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

Как в с++/cli делается рефлексия. Проблема в том, что не понятно как создать массив который содержит управляемые обьекты. Допустим - нужно вызвать метод methodInfo

```
 cli::array<System::Object^,1>^pars 
    = gcnew array<System::Object^,1>^();//тут ошибка
 methodInfo->Invoke(nullptr,pars);
```

Сигнатура метода `Invoke(System::Object^ obj,cli::array<System::Object^> ^parametrs)` , создать unmanaged массив получается, но тогда туда нельзя ложить обьекты.

```
  gcnew array<System::Object^,1>^[10]; так тоже не работает
```

Как же создать такой массив, что бы передать его в parametrs в рефлексию?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442282/using-reflection-invoke

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;

ref class Example {
public:
    long Invoked_Function(Int32 a, Int32* pb) {
        Console::WriteLine("Invoked with {0}, {1}", a, *pb);
        return 999;
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto obj = gcnew Example;
    auto mi = obj->GetType()->GetMethod("Invoked_Function");
    int b = 666;
    int* ptr = &b;
    array<Object^>^ arg = gcnew array <Object^> {42, IntPtr(ptr)};
    long result = (long)mi->Invoke(obj, arg);
    Console::WriteLine("Result = {0}", result);
    return 0;
}
```

это частично даёт ответ на вопрос, потому что пришлось делать так

```
cli::array<System::Object^>^pars  = gcnew cli::array<System::Object^,1>^{};
cli::array<System::Object^>::Resize(pars,10);
```

UPD: Спасибо  Alexander Petrov, второй способ создать массив нужной длинны выглядит так:

```
cli::array<System::Object^>^pars =gcnew cli::array<Object^>(10);
```

А теперь я таки нашёл ссылку на msdn http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/arrays-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017

Comment: `gcnew array<Object^>(10)` - размер в круглых скобках

Comment: Да, так получилось:)