# C++ CLR/CLI array of array<Byte>

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

Собственно какой правильный синтаксис у 2D array?

Попытка:

```
        array<array<Byte>^> ^bytes = gcnew array<array<Byte>^>(4)
        {
            nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr
        };
```

Результат:

> error C3145: $S1: глобальная или статическая переменная не может иметь
>   тип управляемый `"cli::array<cli::array<unsigned char,1> ^,1> ^"`
>
> note: может не объявлять глобальную или статичную переменную или
>   элемент собственного типа, который относится к объекту в куче сборщика
>   мусора

Надо что-бы в него входило по типу:

```
     bytes[2] = gcnew array<Byte>(132);
```

Пазл такой, отгадай синтаксис.
`note` у этой ошибки еще забавнее самой ошибки.

С такой конструкцией тоже не то:

```
    array<Byte, 2> ^bytes = gcnew array<Byte, 2>(4, 100);
    bytes[i] == nullptr
         ^ тут
```

Ошибка `недопустимое число индексов для этого cli::array`

Comment: 2-D array - это `array<Byte,2>^`, а то что вы привели - попытка вложить массив в массив. Массив массивов - это отдельная тема.

Comment: Не понял что не то.

Comment: Надо чтобы в каждый элемент массива влезало по типу и кастингу: `bytes[x] = gcnew array<Byte>(y);`

Comment: Данная модель не позволяет напрямую делать такие преобразования. Вопрос зачем. По идее вы хотите получить из массива - ссылку на обычный массив - тогда приземляйте массив в память, и там оперируйте с ним. Почитайте вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339928/c-sharp-how-to-convert-object-to-intptr-and-back, а так же маршалинг.

Comment: Так то оно так, но массив массивов байт самое распостраненное явление. как еще оперируя индексом можно извлекать необходимые данные? switch/case и завести 40 переменных.. это очень не то, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Я не вижу в вашем вопросе проблему. Сформулируйте что вы хотите преобразовать, откуда и куда. При чём тут  `bytes[i] == nullptr` - это некоректная запись. `с++/cli` - вам даёт полноценный клишный двухмерный массив, где такой изврат не нужен.

Comment: В вопросе, как и в 3 комментарии сверху, я обозначил что требуется конкретно.

Comment: Тогда вопрос должен звучать, "как в cli-массив вложить cli-массив", а не как создать двухмерный массив. Почитайте тут http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-arrays-in-cpp-cli?view=vs-2017

Comment: И это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919976/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81-cli - у вас просто домиков не хватает. Если вы обьявили с домиком, то и gcnew с домиком.

Comment: Тогда это не запихивается в функцию где должно использоваться, если с домиком :) А как ее разименовать в этом clr, я без понятия. Да и ошибка то там о другом, что не может этот параметр быть возвращаемым.. что не понятно.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, магия! ;) с `cli::array` все тоже самое собралось, вероятно оно из другого места подсасывало `array`.